# Declaring an variable initialized in another file

Tags: typescript

I have some code that references a variable I know has already been declared in a file loaded before mine as in

```
if (!Zotero.BetterBibTeX) { ... }
```

but this gets me "Cannot find name 'Zotero'". Is there a way to signal to the typescript compiler that "Zotero" is declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this at the top of the file where you're using `Zotero`:

```
declare let Zotero: {
    BetterBibTeX: any;
};
```

Then you can use `if (!Zotero.BetterBibTeX) { ... }` as you like.

---

If you don't want to have any type checking around the properties on `Zotero`, you can just declare it as an `any` type:

```
declare let Zotero: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to import Zotero into your module. Declaring it as any does solve the compile error.. but that's not really the TypeScript way of importing modules.

```typescript
// -------------------
// File ./zotero.ts
// -------------------
export class Zotero {
  someFunction() {
    // some code..
  }  
}

// -------------------
// File ./main.ts
// -------------------
import { Zotero } from "./zotero.ts";

// Now you can use Zotero.
let z = new Zotero();
z.someFunction();
```

Comment: The code that declares Zotero is not my own (or written in TS); I write an extension that loads after that code has run.

Comment: Ah i see. You can import js-files as well into your TypeScript and might need to write a d.ts file for it. (Or be lazy and declare to any as mentioned by James)